# Python CNTK how to replace input without clone

Tags: python, deep-learning, cntk

I am working now on project in CNTK 2.2 in Python.
I made code:

```
        featureNode = modelCloned.find_by_name('features')
        newNode = {featureNode: cntk.layers.placeholder(name='features')}

        modelFeat = modelCloned.clone(cntk.ops.functions.CloneMethod.clone, newNode)
```

to replace input Feature dimensions in CNTK model that I load from file. Later I apply input map, so I scale features layer to dimension like I want.

Problem is that I do not want to use .clone() funtion. It causes to run out my GPU memory.

Does enybody knows how to replace 'feature' layer without clone funtion?

Best regards,
Chris